# Running Lire image search inside Solr -- how?

Tags: java, image-processing, lucene, solr, image-recognition

I'd like to use Lire image search from within Solr. Lire is built on top of Lucene:

http://www.semanticmetadata.net/lire/

What's the best way to integrate Lire in Solr?

I'd especially appreciate links to any success stories or sample code in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Newly available, as of late 2013: [LireSolr](https://bitbucket.org/dermotte/liresolr/overview), a Solr plugin package for Lire, by the [Lire authors](http://www.semanticmetadata.net/lire/).

A live demo is available: http://demo-itec.uni-klu.ac.at/liredemo/
… images can be searched with several Lire classifiers, e.g. Auto Color Correlogram, PHOG, *et al.*

I’ve personally mirrored it on GitHub: https://github.com/fish2000/liresolr

Answer (score 1):

I do not know of any succesful implementations of this library within Solr, but since both Solr and the library are build on top of Lucene you might be able to build a small plugin to implement this functionality.

[Solr wiki: Plugins](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrPlugins)

[An example plugin](http://sujitpal.blogspot.com/2011/02/solr-custom-search-requesthandler.html)

Next to these two links, I would advise you to download the Solr source code and take a look at the official request handlers. I used the above links and the source code to write a plugin of my own.

Comment: Will start down this road -- thanks for providing a starting point.